# How to change the style of the whole project

Tags: css

When the user check a checkbox, the whole project changes its colors. So all the div's, text,... colors change. How can I do that? I know I need a service but must I add a class to each element? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think you'll need to tell more about what you want to do. Can you give a code example ?
Maybe you can put a css class on the parent block of your project, containing the color info, and style the color of all your elements relating to this parent class. Then, on check, you change that color class on the parent block...

Comment: I need a sort of day/night app. So when the user checks the property. I want to change all the black colors into white and all the white colors into black. I have in my page a few components with div, p, input tags. I thought I put a class to every element. But thats a lot of work

Comment: http://goo.gl/5bdf98 try this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.day-theme` class to the body of the html page. Then define all day colors as inside of the day theme:

```
.day-theme div.something {
    color: white;
}
```

Then define the night theme colors the same way:

```
.night-theme div.something {
    color: black;
}
```

Then to switch from day to night, on the checkbox click handler remove the class `.day-theme` from the body, and add the class `night-theme`. This switches all day colors to night.

Comment: How do I change the body class in the root component?
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <section class="header">
            <h1>App</h1>
            <a [router-link]="['/Setting']">Settings</a>
        </section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
})